# Python text adventure game, ending loop

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops

I am stuck on ending my game and breaking the loop. I have tried rephrasing, putting it in different spots, etc. The game-ending parameter is that if you reach the State of Florida *with* all six items you win, otherwise you lose. Instead, I can get to that final room and it either continues to prompt for input or announces that you've won the game even if you didn't.

```
print("\nMovement commands : North, South, East, or West")
print("Add to inventory: Get item\n")
introduction() # I just cut my long-winded intro. it works.

rooms = {
    'House': {'north': 'Drug Store', 'south': 'Clinic', 'east': 'Kitchen', 'west': 'Craft Store'},
    'Drug Store': {'south': 'House', 'east': 'Electronics Store', 'item': 'Hand Sanitizer'},
    'Electronics Store': {'west': 'Drug Store', 'item': 'ANC Headphones'},
    'Craft Store': {'east': 'House', 'item': 'A Mask'},
    'Clinic': {'north': 'House', 'east': 'CDC', 'item': 'A Vaccine'},
    'CDC': {'west': 'Clinic', 'item': 'Dr Fauci Candle'},
    'Kitchen': {'west': 'House', 'north': 'State of Florida', 'item': 'Anti-viral Spray'},
    'State of Florida': {'item': 'COVID-19'}  # VILLAIN, final room
}

current_room = 'House'  # location variable that will change as player moves
inventory = []  # empty list that will fill as you collect items
directions = ('north', 'south', 'east', 'west')  # possible movements
item = ('hand sanitizer', 'anc headphones', 'a mask', 'a vaccine', 'dr fauci candle',
        'anti-viral spray', 'covid-19') 

while True:
    print('\nYou are in the {}'.format(current_room)) # current game status
    print('Inventory: {}'.format(inventory))
    if 'item' not in rooms[current_room]:
        pass
    else:
        print('You see {}'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
    print('-' * 25)

    command = input('Enter your move:\n').lower().strip()
```

I initially put my game ending statement here, but it just
loops again and then you're stuck in Florida forever because there
is no room attached to it in the dictionary

```
if command in directions:
    if command in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][command]
        if current_room in ['State of Florida']:
            if len(inventory) == 6:
                print('You have contracted COVID-19! G A M E  O V E R')
            else:
                print('You have defeated COVID-19!')
                print('Thank you for protecting your fellow teammates.')
            break
```

It has you win the game when you get here, regardless of inventory requirement
(I have tried this as:)
if len(inventory) == 6 and 'item' == 'COVID-19'
print win
if len(inventory) != 6 and 'item' == 'COVID-19'
print lose

```
    else:
        print('You cannot go that way, please stop running into brick walls.')

elif command == 'get item':
    if 'item' in rooms[current_room]:
        print('{} retrieved! Gold star!'.format(rooms[current_room]['item']))
        inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['item'])
        del rooms[current_room]['item']
    else:
        print('FOCUS! There is nothing in here.')

else:
    print('What did you just call me? RUDE. Try again.')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
        if current_room in ['State of Florida']:
            if len(inventory) == 6:
                print('You have contracted COVID-19! G A M E  O V E R')
            else:
                print('You have defeated COVID-19!')
                print('Thank you for protecting your fellow teammates.')
            break
```

*(aside: you should just do `current_room == 'State of Florida'` instead of using `in`)*

your `break` statement will only break the *innermost* loop.  If you only have one loop (that `while True:`), that should do the trick.  Since it's not working, I suspect you have a loop within that loop.  The inner loop is the one that gets broken, after which execution contains with whatever comes after that loop (and then eventually back to the start of the outer loop).

If that's the case, an easy solution is to put all of this code into a function, so that you can `return` -- a `return` statement immediately exits the function regardless of how many levels of nested loop you're currently in.

Note also that if the intent is to *win* the game when you have six items, rather than *lose* the game, you should invert your `if` statement, e.g. make it so that `if len(inventory) != 6` you lose, rather than the other way around (with the condition being `==` instead of `!=`) as it is in your current code

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I initially tried a function and then was having issues updating my global parameters (current_room, inventory) with what was happening inside the function. Trying to fix this now.

Comment: THAT DID IT. I cannot believe part of it was a copy/paste typo. I moved the game-ending text so many times I flopped it into the wrong place.

Comment: @chantel don't use global vars (it makes things hard to debug) -- pass `current_room`  as a parameter to the function, and have it return `current_room` at the end if the caller needs the updated value.